# Casting 13 digit decimal (timestamp) from db to java Date in MSSQL

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, date, timestamp

I can not resolve my problem. I have 13 digit decimal stored in database, and I need to parse it to the same dat as java.Date is using, so i can compare them in Query.
I strictly do not want to have full timestamp with **'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'**, just **'yyyy-mm-dd'**

```
   @Query(value = "select lg.event_id, lg.level_string, lg.formatted_message, lg.caller_filename, lg.timestmp  from LoggingEvent lg"
        + " where  CONVERT(date,DATEADD(SECOND, timestmp/1000 ,'1970-01-01'),103)= :currentDate")
   List<LoggingEvent> xxx(Date currentDate);
```

I get this output: *No converter found capable of converting from type [java.math.BigDecimal] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query*

Input: 1688118257029
Required output: 2023-06-30

Comment: check the `LocalDate` and `Instant` classes of the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package

Comment: You cannot directly cast a `BigDecimal` to a `Date`, that's what the error message says. Where are you using a `BigDecimal`? Can you use its `longValue()` instead?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to make the parameter fit the criteria rather than convert the value in the table to fit the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the "number" to a "date" in the SELECT. Meaning something like this:

```
select to_timestamp(lg.timestmp/1000)::date AS datetimestmp;
```

Answer (score -1):

('Casting' is not going to help, it does not do magic data conversions).

A Date by definition represents a particular date and time; it cannot do otherwise.

If you want to display only the date, then that is a matter of formatting at the point of display. To convert a numeric value, first find out what the number represents - probably seconds since 1970.  Then, use a suitable constructor like `Date(nnn)` to construct a Date.

There are more suitable replacements for Date, however. I use it only because that's what you mention.